# "Property 'object3D' does not exist on type 'Element'" error when trying to access Element.object3D in A-frame with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, aframe

First, I'm Japanese student. So, please forgive my poor English.
I'm developing a-frame library that make animation with anime.js in TypeScript now.
When I tried to accessing Element.object3D to update value of position, TypeScript generated "Property 'object3D' does not exist on type 'Element'" error.
Here is my code.

```
function updateValue(target: Element, attr: Attribute, value: number) {
switch (attr) {
    case "PositionX":
        target.object3D.position.setX(value)
    case "PositionY":
        target.object3D.position.setY(value)
    case "PositionZ":
        target.object3D.position.setZ(value)

}
```

I realize 'object3D' does not exist on Element but when import a-frame it exists. I tried to require("aframe") but this problem was not fixed.
I apologize for the rudimentary nature of this question and my poor English, but I would be very grateful if you could answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to install `@types/aframe` package, to have the typings for your typescript project.

After that, use [Entity](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aframe/index.d.ts#L124) or [Scene](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aframe/index.d.ts#L244) (I don't know which one is the one that you receive in `updateValue` but those 2 contain `object3D`.

```js
function updateValue(target: Entity, attr: Attribute, value: number) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I forgot type existence of definition file.
The way you suggested solved all the problems!